# How to create cookie in c#.net windows application?

Tags: c#

I have a windows application.Using this i can open a web application.
How to create cookie in Windows application using c#.net

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the win api for creating cookies.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string url, string name, string data);
```

The code above needs to be declared in your code on class level.

The function can then be called from your code (for example a click event handler) as follows:

```
InternetSetCookie("http://www.example.com", "CookieName", "data=cookieData; expires = Sat,01-Jan-2012 00:00:00 GMT; path=/");
```

Those cookies are then set and if you start your browser those cookies are present and are used.

Comment: from where i get this **wininet.dll**

Comment: @bageesh From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331.aspx): Applications that use the WinINet API require Windows NT 4.0 or later, or Windows Me/98/95. For more information about which operating systems or components are required to use a particular programming element, see the Requirements section of the documentation.

Comment: This *really* is the one to use for a winforms or non web form app.

Comment: @SynerCoder Sir, i have tried the same code, but it showing error 
**1) Method must have a return value, 2) Type expected** 
What to do?

Comment: @bageesh The method does have an return value 'bool'... Can you give me your test code?

Comment: [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

private static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string url, string name, string data);

 InternetSetCookie("http://localhost:1155/UI/frmLogin.aspx", "copper", "data=copper; expires = Sat,01-Jan-2012 00:00:00 GMT; path=/");

Comment: @bageesh I added extra information. The actual call must not be declared on class level. But from your code, for example from a click event handler

Comment: This would only set the cookie in Internet Explorer?  (and/or Edge?)

Answer (score 1):

From a `C#.Net Web Application` you can read & write cookies in the following manner:

`Writing a Cookie:`

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
myCookie.Value = "SomeInfo";
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

`Reading a Cookie:`

```
HttpCookie myCookie = Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Net.CookieContainer` class to hold cookie value on request.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
// Do something with this request
```

Which `cookieContainer` is an variable to keep cookie transform between your application and the web. You can initialize it once at the first time your application starts.

Comment: Sir, i  tried 
 `System.Net.CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();`        
           `HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1155/UI/frmLogin.aspx");
           request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
           cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(@"http://localhost:1155/UI/frmLogin.aspx"), cook);`

But from the web application when i am trying to access this cookie,it showing a null reference exception

Comment: How did you create `cook`?

Comment: could you please give me the code

Comment: I've never created a `Cookie` instance by code. I leave it to the Web server. For accessing secured uri, I just send information to login page (such as user, pass). Once that request is done, I can use any secured page on that side as well as I browse the web on the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(args[0]);
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Cookies = request.CookieContainer.GetCookies(request.RequestUri);

            foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cookie:{0} = {1}", cook.Name, cook.Value);
            }
```

Answer (score -3):

Cookies do not exist in windows applications - instead data is either saved in files, or in application settings, or in the registry depending on the quantity of data and it's organisation. You might save it in a database, or an XML file, or as striaght binary info.

But you don't use cookies in windows apps - they are for setting on the client from the server and those concepts do not apply when using Windows apps.

Application settings are probably the easiest:
1) Click on the project in Solution Explorer, choose "Properties". 
2) Double click "Settings.Settings".
3) In the resulting dialog, Create application settings by specifying the Name, Type and Value - leave the "Scope" as "User". 
4) You can now save and load your values easily:

```
        Properties.Settings.Default.MySettingString = "New Value";
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        ...
        string myValue = Properties.Settings.Default.MySettingString;
```

for more Detail See this
   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=create+cookie+in+windows+application+C%23

Comment: I would like to write a cookie from a Windows application.  So that custom hardware can communicate with a web page.