# C# WPF, and data exchange with the browser

Tags: c#, wpf, firefox, opera

I've a C# WPF application developed in VS 2015, and I want the browser to read some data from it. Just a short string. I can save it in a text file, or in a variable but it should be visible to the browser (using JS I suppose). For instance using file:/// doesn't work if the original page is hosted online - as in my case (different source conflict). This should work in Opera and FFox, but looking at their extensions, it seems you can only develop with front-end technologies, which are not enough in my case since I use WPF to look into Win OS, and then I need to share the result with the browser.

I suspect it's possible, and no , it's not to write a malicious piece of code. For instance I can read the details of the graphic card for diagnostic purposes. 
Please help, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers run in a security sandbox which is intended to stop them reading or writing files to the file system.
You could write to the user's appdata. There are various javascript frameworks which persist data to there so they can provide offline or static data.
I don't think that is a good plan though.

I suggest your first candidate would be a cookie.
Quick google on how to do that, I find:
[How to create cookie in c#.net windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284172/how-to-create-cookie-in-c-net-windows-application)

From a web page you can use the content of a cookie dynamically. So you could change what you see in the web page after it's up and running from some process in your wpf app and do a counter or whatever.

I've not used this with windows apps and a browser but I have with a web app and Silverlight. I'm afraid I don't have that code to hand though.

Comment: Thanks Andy, it looks good, providing I'm not forced to use IE.

Comment: I would think you'll be ok with IE. It  was maybe 7 years or so ago I did that Silverlight stuff and our primary target browser was IE. If you have problems there post a comment and I'll see if I can find that code.

Comment: Thanks, but we support only Chrome, Opera, and FFox. Unfortunately setting a cookie from WPF *that works*, is not simple. Eg. Opera uses SQLlite, and it's easy to add a cookie from an Addon, but complicated from WPF. It seems a Mission Impossible talking with the browser ! Why it's so complicated?

Comment: OK, I decided to POST my string to my website. I think this is the easiest way, then with AJAX I'll get it in my browser.

Comment: You can also add script to a page from the webbrowser control. I would think you can then add a variable or set a cookie.

Comment: Cookies have the same problem, it's not easy to make them readable by the browser. I suspect it's the same sandbox concept that keeps isolated the browser from the device's OS. POSTing data is far simpler, and my code is already working fine.